How do I fix "boot.asm:21: error: symbol `puts.mpmp' not defined"
Heres my code
org 0x7C00
bits 16


%define ENDL 0x0D, 0x0A

start:
jmp main

puts:
push si
push ax

.loop:
lodsb
or al, al
jz .done
mov bh, 0
int 0x10

jmp .mpmp

.done:
 pop ax
 pop si
 ret

main:
mov ax, 0
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x7C00
   mov si, msg_bootstring
   call puts
hlt

.halt:
jmp .halt



msg_bootstring: db "MudOS 1.0 Beta Development Preview", ENDL, 0
msg_bootstring1: db "Starting", ENDL, 0


times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0AA55h


I tried to do it again but it just shows the same error

The error doesn't seem to be for the code you are showing. Are you sure you saved the file in your text editor before you ran NASM?

Yes I saved it but it didnt work Micheal Petch

Are you saving it into the same directory you are assembling it in? The error you are showing definitely isn't for the code you are showing in the question. Did you copy and paste thee right code to Stackoverflow? There is no reference to puts in the code you have here

Could you give me the fixed code for it thank you micheal petch

C:\Program Files\NASM>

C:\Users\raili\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\CodeNameMudOS\src\bootloader Micheal petch

The termnial just closes

Notepad++ is my app

Yes, I did Idk whats happening tho

Even when I rename it its still showing the error

https://i.ibb.co/gz0Zyg9/Screenshot-2024-04-19-200946.png

https://i.ibb.co/cNqjTmd/Screenshot-2024-04-19-201115.png

The code in your question is not what is in your editor! Why not hit edit on your question and paste the correct code here?

Thanks for putting the actual code you are using into the question.

Maybe you meant jmp .loop instead of jmp .mpmp . YOu get the error because there is no label .mpmp


puts:
 ...
 jmp .mpmp
main:


Because of the prefixed dot, NASM treats the .mpmp label as a local label. Because this local label sits between the global labels puts and main, the label's full name becomes puts.mpmp. The error message then says that you have forgotten to define such a label in your program. Indeed, the code should have been using jmp .loop to be correct.
Another error that NASM can't possibly detect is that you forgot to insert the instruction that sets AH to the function number for the BIOS.Teletype service.
    org 0x7C00
    bits 16
    
    %define ENDL 0x0D, 0x0A
    
    start:
    jmp main
    
    puts:
     push si
     push ax
    .loop:
     lodsb
     or   al, al
     jz   .done
     mov  bh, 0
     mov  ah, 0x0E    ; BIOS.Teletype
     int  0x10
     jmp  .loop
    .done:
     pop  ax
     pop  si
     ret

